# Resize whole app depending on device resolution

Tags: android, ios, resize, zooming

I've already searched a lot for how to handle different screen sizes. But one thing I couldn't find out:

Is there a possibility just to scale the whole app, instead of the contents? Like you just zoom in the whole app. The iPad does it with iPhone apps, so I think it should be kinda possible.

And - of course - is this possible for iOS and Android Apps?

Comment: `...to scale the whole app, instead of the contents?` what is the difference between these ?

Comment: Basically I don't want to scale e.g. a Label by changing the font-size, changing all of the items one by one, ... because this will make tons of problems. I just want to zoom in without really changing anything